# MySite Feature Activated Document Library

Tags: 2013, feature, mysite

I would like to modify the Document Library for each users mysite during creation to include a custom content type. I figured a feature would solve this problem.  However, when activating the features and looking at the list available "Documents" is not available.

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{

    using (SPSite site = (SPSite)properties.Feature.Parent)
    {

        foreach (SPWeb web in site.AllWebs)
        {
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            //THINGS FALL APART!
            SPList docs = web.Lists.TryGetList("Documents"); 

            //Add Custom Content Type to List
            //SPContentType contentType = web.ContentTypes["Custom Document Type"];
            //docs.ContentTypesEnabled = true;
            //docs.ContentTypes.Add(contentType);
            //docs.Update();
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
            web.Update();
        }

    }
```

I have the feature scope set to site ... I can see that the lists available includes "User Photos".

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just for understanding: You are activating the feature on a my site, once the my site is up and running (not sometime during a creation process or something)? And you would like to ensure that the Documents library on each web (!) has this content type? I'm asking because you're using AllWebs and not every web might have a "Documents" list. On which web did you see the "User Photos" list you are mentioning?

Comment: @Pzyon, Ideally I would like to have my new custom content type added to mysite document libraries as the default on site creation, but I am trying to do things one step at a time.  I was debugging the feature activation using my Farm account and I navigated to http://mysites.domain.com/ > Site Settings > Site Collection Features > My Feature > Activate.  I have continued my search and some say that the documents (personal and shared) are not available at site creation time.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Ok. So have a my site (site collection) which you can access in the browser. Then you manually activate your feature which tries to add the content type to the list. Correct? Can you see the list in Site Cettings then? I mean in the browser, not while debugging. I am just asking because on my my site the list is there and I do not see, why it shouldn't be there for you.

Comment: @Pzyon I think you are on to something.  I was trying to add the feature at mysites.domain.com, When I go to Site Settings > Site Lists and Libraries I don't see documents.  If I navigate to mysites.domain.com/personal/user I can see the Documents list.  How to I change the solution to target the /personal site?

Comment: You said it's a site collection scoped feature, that would mean you simply need to activate it on mysites.domain.com/personal/user. Just be aware that you iterate over every web in that site collection and try to add to content type to the "Documents" list. Maybe it's enough to just do it on the RootWeb? It depends on your needs.. If you really want to do it on every web, then maybe you should check if the list is actually there..

Comment: Isn't my foreach statement iterating each site collection?  The problem is that the feature doesn't show up on the /personal sites.

Comment: No, it's iterating every SPWeb (=site) in the SPSite (=site collection) on which the feature is being activated. If your feature isn't hidden, then I do not understand, why you can not see it.

Comment: Feature isn't hidden.  When I evaluate web.AllWebs it has a count of 1.  I know for a fact in Central Admin I have 10-15 site collections under the mysite host.

Comment: Yes, the AllWebs has a count of 1 because the site collection contains only 1 web (the RootWeb) with no sub-webs. The "My Site Host" (I guess in your case this is mysites.domain.com) is the site collection which "manages" the my sites. The actual my sites however are created some where else (i.e. in a different site collection), for example mysites.domain.com/personal/my_user. And one these site collections you need to activate your feature. I'm afraid I really can't tell you, why you can not see it. Maybe you can try to activate it using PowerShell (Enable-SPFeature).

Comment: @Pzyon  I have changed the feature scope to Web and it began to work.  It is still a work in progress so I will post a solution when I have it all worked out.  Thanks for your help so far.